# How I can get list all scenario from specflow dll?

Tags: nunit, specflow, testrail

Or from other place..

- What I want: get all scenario names on start test, but **without start all tests**.
- What I tried: by assembly reflection I scanned content, but one contain only feature names and method names. Not scenario names. (from this: [Get list of tests in nunit library programmatically without having to run tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724479/get-list-of-tests-in-nunit-library-programmatically-without-having-to-run-tests))
  Also exist ScenarioContext, but it contain only current names. Not all existing in testsuite.

What i am using:

- Specflow for describe.
- NUnit for run. VS2019.
- TestRail for result collect. TestSuite contains testName equal test describe in Specflow.

I hope it  possible.
Thanks to all!

Comment: You can have a look at the `.feature.cs` files generated from each feature file. They should be NUnit test classes. You should be able to use class reflection to read the attributes over the class names and methods.

Comment: Thank U,Greg!
Yes, I tried get attributes through  NUnit class reflection. 
Here my code: https://pastebin.com/hfve49A2

In **.feature.cs** class generated scenario name contains in 
`[NUnit.Framework.DescriptionAttribute("First method. SaveForExample")]`
 I researched and obtain inherinatce `DescriptionAttribute : PropertyAttribute`.
https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/DescriptionAttribute.cs

And PropertyAttribute.cs contains `readonly PropertyBag properties = new PropertyBag();` and `property Properties`.

But I do`nt have result. =(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I`m finded it!

```
List<string> scenLst = new List<string>();
try
{
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "project.dll"));
    var types = assembly.GetTypes();                    
    foreach (Type t in types){
        foreach (var method in t.GetMethods()){
            foreach (var attributes in tm.GetCustomAttributes())
            {
            if (attributes is DescriptionAttribute){
                var d = propertyList.Properties["Description"][0].ToString();
                if(d != null){
                    scenLst.Add();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex){...}
return scenLst;
}
```

To get tags use CategoryAttribute (from NUnit).